# Missing timestamps for uploaded images

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, carrierwave, timestamp

I have mongoid and carrierwave-mongoid gems in my project (for avatars in user model) and need timestamps in uploaded images URL. I know there is Wiki page for this ([https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Use-a-timestamp-in-file-names](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3a-Use-a-timestamp-in-file-names)) but there is note "This does not seem to be reliable. I'd strongly recommend saving the timestamp to the database and reading it from the model to generate the filename instead of using this method." and I'm not sure how to do that.

I think Rails should generate timestamps for images URL automatically or from specific attribute right? So I'm not sure what is the right name for this attribute or what is the right approach for this with Mongoid and carrierwave-mongoid.

Could you please provide me some info or link where I can found more about this or info about the solution.

Because my repo on GitHub is private I did this Gist (https://gist.github.com/2355128) where you can see my user model and avatar uploader.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This may be more generic than you want for an answer, but hopefully it will get you to an appropriate solution.  The unique ObjectID that is used for the default _id fields in MongoDB has a timestamp "built in", BSON::ObjectId would be what you are looking for in Mongoid to extract it.

There is also a write up on it here:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Optimizing+Object+IDs#OptimizingObjectIDs-Extractinsertiontimesfromidratherthanhavingaseparatetimestampfield.

Hence, you could use a wrapper around the ObjectID to construct your URLs and avoid the use of an extra timestamp entirely.